# How to animate a qpushbutton background's gradient to go from left to right on hover?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, gradient, qtstylesheets

I'm practicing my programming skills and I am trying to build a login-system application with `PyQt`. I designed it after [Login V4](https://colorlib.com/etc/lf/Login_v4/index.html) . Now I'm trying to achieve that cool gradient animation from the Login button when you hover over it. But the `CSS` code to animate something like that doesn't work in `qt stylesheet`. I designed the app with the Qt Designer. Is it even possible to create that animation in `pyqt`? If yes, how do you that?

My app looks like this:

[image]

The stylesheet code of the Login button:

```
QPushButton#login_button {
font: 75 10pt "Microsoft YaHei UI";
font-weight: bold;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgb(61, 217, 245), stop:1 rgb(240, 53, 218));
border-style: solid;
border-radius:21px;
}
```

Comment: I think it's doable if you change the start and stop colors of the gradient a few hundreds times in a loop upon cursor hovering. You might want to write a separate function that returns those, after taking in argument something like (color1, color2, shift_percentage). Do you see where I'm going?

Comment: At 0% you have for example `start=cyan, stop=magenta`, then at 10% `start=0.9*cyan+0.1*magenta, stop=0.9*magenta+0.1*cyan` etc. and you update the stylesheet in a rapid succession. Of course replace cyan and magenta with their rgb equivalent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you suspect, Qt Style Sheet does not support animations. In this case, an alternative is to use QXAnimation as QVariantAnimation:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class LoginButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(60, 60)

        self.color1 = QtGui.QColor(240, 53, 218)
        self.color2 = QtGui.QColor(61, 217, 245)

        self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            self,
            valueChanged=self._animate,
            startValue=0.00001,
            endValue=0.9999,
            duration=250
        )

    def _animate(self, value):
        qss = """
            font: 75 10pt "Microsoft YaHei UI";
            font-weight: bold;
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            border-style: solid;
            border-radius:21px;
        """
        grad = "background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 {color1}, stop:{value} {color2}, stop: 1.0 {color1});".format(
            color1=self.color1.name(), color2=self.color2.name(), value=value
        )
        qss += grad
        self.setStyleSheet(qss)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Forward)
        self._animation.start()
        super().enterEvent(event)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self._animation.setDirection(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Backward)
        self._animation.start()
        super().enterEvent(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)

    for i in range(5):
        button = LoginButton()
        button.setText("Login")
        lay.addWidget(button)
    lay.addStretch()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I knew you will help me @eyllanesc, thank you so much, this helped me a lot! This is amazing, you are amazing! Can you tell me please where I can learn more about creating animations in pyqt ?